# Insert moving image or gif in UI button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I tried placing animated gif in UI button image but it doesn't move. Is this possible to place a animated gif or moving image in UI button image?

Comment: Do you mean **animated** gif?

Comment: @mjwills yes. I already have a spritesheet

Comment: Is a spritesheet the same as an animated gif?

Comment: @mjwills. I don't know what do you mean by spritesheet animated gif. But I use this spritesheet to create animated prefab

Answer (score 4):

- If you don't have a video format supporte by Unity yet you could generate a `WebM` from multiple `PNG` frames. It requires the `Adobe MediaEncoder` (or whatever program you find) to generate a `WebM` video from them. There are also other [video formats supported by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html), I used WebM in specific to support transparency.
- If you have already a **video** format that is [supported by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html) you can directly jump to section **3. Use the animation in Unity for UI** here below

#### 1. Save your animation as PNG files

I don't know where your animation comes from exactly but you have to save each frame as a PNG file. Best with according name postfix (e.g. `frame_001.png`, `frame_002.png`, ...).

#### 2. Encode the PNG files to a WebM video format

1. Install the WebM codec for Adobe Premiere and MediaEncoder using the WebM_Premiere_v1.1.0.msi or download it at https://www.fnordware.com/WebM/
2. Open the AdobeMediaEncoder
3. Go to `File`->`AddSource...`
   [image]
4. Select the first frame of your animation. E.g. the ./Source/2.BlenderOutput
   [image]
5. In the `Queue` view click on the current target codec
   [image]
6. As format select `WebM`
   [image]
7. in the `Image Settings` section you can either adjust the setting sor simply click on `Match Source`
   [image]
8. In the Codec `Settings` switch to `VP8` since Unity doesn't support `VP9` (yet?)
   [image]
9. You might want to make further adjustments but the most important: Enable `Include Alpha Channel`
   [image]
10. When you think you are done hit `Ok` at the bottom of the window
     [image]
11. Back in the `Queue` view click on the play symbol to start encoding
     [image]
12. after finishing and closing AdobeMediaEncoder you will find the result in the same folder your source frames where in
     [image]

#### 3. Use the animation in Unity for UI (works with other video formats as well)

1. Import the generated files e.g. `[0001-0027].webm` and `[0001-0027].webm.xmp` into your UnityProject. And for the importsettings set them to

   [image]

   maybe that's the default anyway (I don't remember ;) ).
2. On the according `Button` GameObject remove the component `Image`

   [image]

   and replace it with a `RawImage` component

   [image]

   Make sure to reference this `RawImage` again in the `Button`'s `Target Graphic` field.

   [image]
3. Create a new `RenderTexture`

   [image]

   and use it as the `Texture` of the `RawImage` component

   [image]
4. Anywhere in your Scene (I simply did it on the same object) add a `VideoPlayer` component

   [image]

   make it render into the created `RenderTexture`

   [image]

   and as `VideoClip` select the imported webm (or other format) video.

   [image]

   Then you could start the video via script ... but I usually make it `Play On Awake` and `Loop`

   [image]

---

Result

[image]

---

Note that as Unity states in the  [`RawImage` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html)

> Keep in mind that this will create an extra draw call with each RawImage present, so it's best to use it only for backgrounds or temporary visible graphics.

so you should keep the usage of this as rare as possible.